# one of the fields is count(*) NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Can I do mapping to query like this :

```
select id,name,address,(select count(*) from account where record_id=id ) as counter
from data where id = :id
```

Currently , I'm using a native SQL .

```
class person
{
    public virtual long Id{get;set;}
    public virtual string Name{get;set;}
    public virtual string Address{get;set;}
    public virtual long Counter{get;set;}
}
```

mapping :

```
<property name="Counter" formula="(select count(*) from account where record_id=id )"      type="long"/>
```

Comment: Ok, now I understand the classes you want to use. I adapted my answer, please take a look.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you should use [formula](http://kyle.baley.org/UsingAnNHibernateFormulaToAidSearching.aspx).

Your mappings might look like this:

```
<property name="CountOfAccounts"
    formula="(select count(*) from account where account.id = id)"/>
```

Comment: thanks. but now I have a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: thanks. but now I have a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception . my class like this: class Counter { int Id { get; private set; } string Name { get; set; } string Address { get; set; } Counter{ get; private set; } }

Comment: and how would NHibernate know what is the value of "id" ?

Comment: id is always known. it is embedded field(i don't remember exact definition)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the business classes you want to use. You could have these classes;

```
class Person
{
  int Id { get; private set; }
  string Name { get; set; }
  string Address { get; set; }
  IList<Account> Accounts { get; private set; } 
}

class Account
{
  // ...
}
```

Then you map it "normally" as one-to-many. Don't forget to make use of lazy loading. You may make it bidirectional.

You may create an optimized query which prevents loading the accounts just to count them:

```
select 
  p,
  size(p.Accounts)
from
  Person p
where 
  p.id = :id
```

This produces quite a similar query then yours. You get a Person in the first column and the number of accounts in the second.